Safari fetch CORS error from code, exact same from console works
Very straightforward API call using fetch:
fetch('https://<api-domain>/<endpoint-path>', {headers:{Accept: 'application/json', Authorization: 'Bearer <token>'}});

When I open Safari and don't open dev tools/console, request sometimes works the first time I open the page making the request on load. If I refresh the page, I always get

Origin  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

but if ctrl + click in network tab --> copy as fetch --> paste into console --> run; it always works.
Request triggered from console has the following extra headers compared to the original:
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:authority: <api-domain>
:path: <endpoint-path>
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, be
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _ga_<blablabla>;_ga=<blablabla>
Host: <api-domain>

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?
